# Connection error with ftputil: DH_KEY_TOO_SMALL

Tags: python, ssl, ftp, ftplib, ftputil

When I connect to an FTP server (Pure-FTPd) with `ftputil`, I get the following error:

```py
import ftputil
from ftplib import FTP_TLS

class TLSFTPSession(FTP_TLS):

    def __init__(self, host, userid, password):
        FTP_TLS.__init__(self)
        self.set_debuglevel(2)
        self.connect(host, 21)
        self.login(userid, password)
        self.prot_p()

ftp = ftputil.FTPHost(host, user, pw, session_factory=TLSFTPSession)
```

This returns:

```
FTPOSError: [SSL: DH_KEY_TOO_SMALL] dh key too small (_ssl.c:997)
Debugging info: ftputil 5.0.4, Python 3.10.5 (win32)
```

So I tried to apply the solution I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64885788/dh-key-too-small-python-ftp-on-whonix) by adding `self.context.set_ciphers('DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1')` to the `__init__` method of the custom `TLSFTPSession` class:

```py
class TLSFTPSession(FTP_TLS):

    def __init__(self, host, userid, password):
        FTP_TLS.__init__(self)
        self.set_debuglevel(2)
        self.connect(host, 21)
        self.login(userid, password)
        self.prot_p()
        self.context.set_ciphers('DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1')
```

However, this didn't help either. Any idea?

Comment: Please call `self.context.set_ciphers('DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1')` before calling `self.connect(..)`

Comment: And/Or ask the owner of that FTP server to read https://weakdh.org/sysadmin.html and fix its configuration to have better security.

Comment: Yes, calling `set_ciphers` before `connect` worked (which makes perfect sense)! Unfortunately, this is an FTP server I do not control, so I have to live with it.